# Null independent column wise mean calculation in Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to calculate the mean of 3 three columns in Python. Here is the catch- 
If all 3 row values of my 3 columns are not null then my mean will be (x+y+z)/3.

If one of my row value is null (suppose z), then my mean should be (x+y)/2.

I'm storing there mean values in a seperate column which is part of the pandas dataframe.

I'm looking for the best approach as my dataset has over 2 million rows.
My data is below.

Thanks in advance.

```
     A    B  C
0    1    2  3   # = (1+2+3)/3 = 2
1    4  NaN  6   # = (4+6)/2 = 5
2  NaN    8  9   # = (8+9)/2 = 8.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply the `numpy.nanmean` function along axis `0` (columns). This is the default axis so you will get the same result with omitting `axis = 0`. If you want the means row-wise use `axis = 1`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [2.3, 4.5, 2.1, np.nan, 6.7],
    'b': [2.4, 5.6, np.nan, np.nan, 7.1],
    'c': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.9]
})

colmeans = df.apply(np.nanmean, axis = 0)

# colmeans
# a    3.900000
# b    5.033333
# c    0.900000
# dtype: float64

rowmeans = df.apply(np.nanmean, axis = 1)

# 0    2.35
# 1    5.05
# 2    2.10
# 3     NaN
# 4    4.90
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think they wanted row-wise mean of the three columns, so axis=1?

Comment: ok, then the huge east turned image confused me :) I will update

Comment: Thanks a ton! Apologies for my bad question posting skills :)